# I need to make my code composable reusable, dot know how to do that for images

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, material-design

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Easur.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOwZd.png)I want to use my CityList composable for two different pages, and so I want to make it reusable. How can I make it so this isn't so hard coded. I want to add the images and text later

I looked around the Android Studio site, couldn't find what I was looking for though[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIN7v.png)

Comment: First, don't post images of code.  Post the code itself.  Second, why are you passing a List<Activity>. I cannot think of any case where it would ever be correct to have a list of activities.  You should never be creating activities yourself, the framework does that.  You should not be passing the Activity around anywhere that doesn't absolutely need a UI Context, and that should be minimal.  You should not be storing Activites in a variable unless it's transient or absolutely necessary, due to risk of memory leaks.  This is a major architecture mistake.